# How can I make a fabric8 k8s client in my AWS Lambda function authenticate properly with EKS?

Tags: aws-lambda, fabric8, amazon-eks

I have a snippet of code that I'm invoking as a Lambda Function in AWS. Inside the lambda function, I'm making a call to an EKS cluster using the fabric8 client. All I'm doing at this point is having the client retrieve unbound PVCs:

```
        KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();

        MixedOperation<PersistentVolumeClaim, PersistentVolumeClaimList,
                DoneablePersistentVolumeClaim, Resource<PersistentVolumeClaim,
                DoneablePersistentVolumeClaim>> operation = client.persistentVolumeClaims();
        PersistentVolumeClaimList pvcList = operation.inAnyNamespace().list();
        java.util.List<PersistentVolumeClaim> unboundItems = pvcList.getItems()
                .stream()
                .filter(pvc -> !"bound".equalsIgnoreCase(pvc.getStatus().getPhase()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

One of the DevOps guys at work added my user ARN to a ConfigMap, so if I run this locally and just passing the AWS credentials through System Properties, I get results back. He has also experimented with adding the Lambda role ARN, but it doesn't work. If I deploy the code in my lambda, I get a 403 error:

```
"errorMessage": "Failure executing: GET at: https://XYZ.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims. Message: persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"persistentvolumeclaims\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=403, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=persistentvolumeclaims, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"persistentvolumeclaims\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Forbidden, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).",
  "errorType": "io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException"
```

I'm pretty new to k8s, fabric8, and EKS, so apologies if I'm doing something obviously dumb here. I do have a ~/.kube/config file, which I include in the Lambda ZIP file (I've been told that this is insecure). The config file seems to work fine when I run the code locally. I'm setting the **kubeconfig** system property to point to the file. I understand that there needs to be some external mechanism like `aws-iam-authenticator` available to the k8s client to properly authenticate with EKS. What I don't know is if I should use some other mechanism when this runs in a Lambda?

I found an [article](https://www.nickaws.net/aws/2018/09/03/Interacting-with-EKS-via-Lambda.html) that describes the general process of having a Lambda talk to EKS, and I've played around with the IAM role configuration as suggested, as well as adding the lambda role ARN to a **ConfigMap**, but so far nothing has helped. I'm really blocked on this, and if anyone has any tips, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please try overriding default config by providing token and url like this https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/CreatePod.java#L62

Comment: @RohanKumar, how/where would I obtain the OAuth token to pass into the Config?

Comment: @RohanKumar, I tried your suggestion. I'm now reading the kube config file in as a string and calling Config.fromKubeconfig() with the string, then passing the Config object to the DefaultKubernetesClient constructor. I'm still getting the auth error, but it seems like the underlying issue is that fabric8 can't find the authenticator command (aws) specified in the **user:** section of the kubeconfig file. If that's not available inside the lambda, I'm not quite sure what to use.

Comment: by token I meant `ServiceAccount` token. There might be a `ServiceAccount` created  by cluster administrator which you can use.